# Google Cloud PubSub Accessing Query Parameters

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

I have a system that publishes messages to Cloud PubSub but the data of the message is passed as query parameters in a GET request (as opposed to using the body of POST request).

1. Does PubSub even accept HTTP GET requests as published messages?
2. Is there any way to access these query parameters using the Apache Beam
   Java SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to the first question, the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub REST API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/) states which kind of HTTP method is accepted for each of the API calls. Publish requires the POST method.